# How do I pass objects as a parameter in a method?

Tags: scala

I started using scala and spark recently. I am open to advice on making this better.

I have 3 Objects in folder1 with the same number of val's and same names.

```
  object Obj1 {

  val className = "className1"

  val dimensions = Array(
    "d1",
    "d2"
  )

  val metrics = Array(
    "m1",
    "m2"
  )

  object Obj2 {

  val className = "className2"

  val dimensions = Array(
    "d1",
    "d2"
  )

  val metrics = Array(
    "m1",
    "m2"
  )

  object Obj3 {

  val className = "className3"

  val dimensions = Array(
    "d1",
    "d2"
  )

  val metrics = Array(
    "m1",
    "m2"
  )
```

I want to simplify this:

```
  val df1 = method(Obj1.className, Obj1.dimensions, Obj1.metrics)

  val df2 = method(Obj2.className, Obj2.dimensions, Obj2.metrics)

  val df3 = method(Obj3.className, Obj3.dimensions, Obj3.metrics)
```

by creating a method that passes a list of the Objects calling specific val's in the Objects.

I tried writing this but it doesn't work. How can I create a method or redesign so I can pass Objects into newMethod?

```
def newMethod(obj: Object) = {
  val df = method(obj.className, obj.dimensions, obj.metrics)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a Trait:

```
trait Obj {
  def className: String
  def dimensions: Array[String]
  def metrics: Array[String]
}
```

You'll have your ObjX objects implement that trait like `object Obj1 extends Obj` and then change the signature of your `newMethod` to `def newMethod(obj: Obj)`.